# C# optimal way to populate a List<Class> from List<string>

Tags: c#

I have very simple code which explains itself.

```
List<string> Files = new List<string>( Directory.EnumerateFiles(PathLocation));
```

However I now wish to make life complicated and I have a file object.

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an optimal way to populate the string property of the class, ie is there a better way than using a foreach loop or similar?

Comment: The code may explain itself, but the question does not. ;) What exactly is it you want to populate? Is the result supposed to be a list it the format `List<File>`, where each `File` is populated with the result from `Directory.EnumerateFiles(...)`?

Comment: Thanks, some good answers which are much appreciated. I accepted fastest answer as quality is good for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the contents of `Files` into a `List<File>`:

```
var files = Files.Select(f => new File { Filename = f })
                 .ToList();
```

The same using **LINQ** syntax:

```
var query = from f
            in Files 
            select new File { Filename = f };

var files = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Both are LINQ, the former method- and the latter query-syntax ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ `Select` to replace foreach loop:

```
List<File> files = Files.Select(s => new File() { FileId = id, Filename = s})
                        .ToList();
```

But needless to create new `List` to optimize your code:

```
List<File> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(PathLocation)
                            .Select(s => new File() { FileId = id, Filename = s})
                            .ToList();
```

MSDN is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
List<File> Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(PathLocation).Select(f=> new File { FileId = /*...*/, Filename = f }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<File> bigList;
var stringList = bigList.Select(f=>f.Filename);
```